# Sqlite Prepare Failed: no such table<tablename>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have created sqlite database.

I add this sqlite file in my application but when I run the app in the simulator and check the sqlite file's path in document directory and I open the sqlite file on document directory's path at that time the table which I have created does not appear.

In local copy I can see the table also in my project folder I can see the table but on the path of simulator I am not able to see the table

so in my console it shows me the error:

> Sqlite Prepare failed: no such table

Comment: Your sqilte database file doesn't get copied in document directory so the error you are getting is obvious.

Comment: I can see my sqlite file at that path but no. tables in this sqlite file is zero. so I get this error.

Comment: As said by @HarshIT, your `DB` isn't copied to document directory, delete the app from `iphone-simulator` and `clean` the project. If still not solved then `remove-reference` of `DB` from `project-explorer` and `add` it again.

Comment: How can I remove-reference of DB from project-explorer? I don't know because I am new to iphone

Comment: just select and delete it, it will ask to remove reference and move to trash....

Comment: ok I have done that I have also reset the simulator and delete .sqlite file from my xcode.

Comment: hope you specified the file name properly as iOS programming is case sensitive.

Comment: I have checked it thrice friend

Comment: have fari thi bundle ma file add kari ne tamaro code run kari ne doc directory ma check karo. have aavij jase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17607/discussion-between-harshit-and-khushbu)

Comment: thank you my dear friend for helping me but I got the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My response below assumes that your database is properly formatted and functional. You could test easily via the command line. In my own apps, all tab bar controllers apps, I place the db access code in the app delegate. The two methods in the app delegate are as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rootController]; 
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Also:

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbName.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I have implemented same code but in appdelegate I forgot to write [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded]; in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Answer (score 2):

If you've tried everything and are still getting this error.. even if you've tried resetting the iOS Simulator.  Try installing the app in the iOS simulator and then manually uninstalling it (select Home and long select the app icon and delete it) and then reset the simulator.

I don't know why but I tried everything else, spent hours banging my head against the wall.  Then this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the sqlite file in your xcode project and locate it like so:

> ```
> NSString *pathToSQL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
> pathForResource:@"sqlname" ofType:@"sql"];
> ```

Comment: I got the path in my console and at that path I have .sqlite file but this sqlite file contains zero tables.

Comment: then its not objective c problem, rather a problem with your file. have you loaded your qlite file somewhere to check wether it is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Target Membership" of the sql file is set properly, so that the project "sees" it:

1) click on the sql file in the left-pane of Xcode

2) open/show the File Inspector (right pane)

3) Under "Target Membership", make sure the "check" is "checked"

That's it. Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.